# asp.net mvc post data and page refresh (session variable vs tempData vs detect F5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i am teaching myself MVC and am struggling to work out the best solution to my problem. I have a search controller with a large amount of input fields. I will also have multiple overloads of the search fields eg basic search advanced search searchByCategory etc.

When the search form is posted i redirect to another action that displays the search results. If i press f5 the get action is fired again as opposed to the search results being refreshed in the action that my post redirects to. Ideally i would like to redirect to a search results `Action Method` without using the query string, or detect when refresh is hit and requery the database and just use different actions within the same search controller. I have read a lot of posts about this and the only 2 solutions i can find is using a session variable or TempData.Can anybody advise as to what is the best practice

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't you want to use the query string? I'd argue it's the most sensible thing to use

Comment: hi query string seems to be the preferred method, but with lots of parameters it is too long. Also if there is any sensitive data it there is privacy and security issues. in 99% of scenarios its probably best, but from a personal view i also think it can look ugly. This is mainly a learning experience to find out what options are available and what the industry standard practices are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  thanks

I have had a chance to revisit this. the problem was i neglected to mention that i am using `jQuery mobile` which uses Ajax by default even for a normal `Html.BeginForm`. I was also returning a view which i have since learned will not updated the URL but only render new html for the current controller. my solution is to set the action, controller and html attributes in the `Html.Beginform`as follows :

```
@Html.BeginForm("Index", "SearchResults", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" })
```

inside the parameters for the index action of the searchResults controller I have a `viewModel` that represents the `fieldset` of the form that i am posting. The `data-ajax="false"` disables the Ajax on the form post and MVC takes care of matching the form post parameters to my model. This allows the `url` to update and when i press f5 to refresh the controller re-queries the database and updates the search results.

Thanks everybody for your help. I was aware of `TempData` but it is good to know that this is preferred over session data so i voted up your answer

Answer (score 5):

**From the Comments**
Most of the time I prefer to use `TempData` in place of `QueryString`. This keeps the Url clean.

**Question**

> Can anybody advise as to what is the best practice

**Answer**

Once the data is sent to `Action Method` to get the results from Database after then As per my knowledge you can use `TempData` to store the posted data. It is like a `DataReader` Class, once read, Data will be lost. So that stored data in `TempData` will become null.

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"] //Once read, data will be lost
```

So to persist the data even after the data is read you can Alive it like below

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"];
TempData.Keep();                   //Data will not be lost for all Keys
TempData.Keep("keyName");          //Data will not be lost for this Key
```

*`TempData` works in new Tabs/Windows also, like `Session` variable does.*

You could use `Session` Variable also, Only major problem is that `Session` Variable are very heavy comparing with `TempData`. Finally you are able to keep the data across Controllers/Area also.

Hope this post will help you alot.

Comment: thanks for the reply. tempData seems like a very nice way to manage this. Why should sessions be avoided?

Comment: TempData has the disadvantage of being backed by the Session State, it's just a wrapper with some extended behavior.  This means that things that break session, like mobile devices not storing cookies, or load balancers with insufficient backing cache configurations could cause odd behavior or errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to even call `Get Method` after performing search although its good habit in case of if your are performing any add/update/delete operation in database. But in your case you can just return the `View` from your post method and no need to store data in `tempdata` or `session` until you really don't need them again. So do something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult PerformSearch(SearchModel model)
    {
         // Your code to perform search
          return View(model);
    }
```

Hope this will help.